# VSTO: CustomTaskPane Header Color change

Tags: c#, colors, header, vsto, customtaskpane

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pfET.png)

How can I make the Custom Task Pane Header Color more match the inner usercontrol ?

I already google this problem ,these are the search results:

（1） Add-in Express 【Third-Parties:not free】

（2） Shared Add-in  【find that:This project has been removed in Visual Studio 2012
This project is still available in Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 under (Other Project Types > Extensibility) 】

（3） public class Connect : Object, Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2, Office.IRibbonExtensibility, Office.ICustomTaskPaneConsumer  【from:https://learn.microsoft.com .Hard to execute ,hard to understand without a instance】

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.